# Debugging excel crash

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with several diagramms which sources are linked to ranges in other worksheets.

For some diagramms the range for legend-entries and the range for the data and horizontal axis labels are not connected (see screenshot).
[image]
When i hold control and try to select a new range while having the "pick sources"-dialog opened excel simply crahses without an error message or some kind of a warning.

I tried in safe mode with the same result. My question is: is there a debugging tool or something like a log?

EDIT: i disabled all COM-plugins also

EDIT 2: i repaired the office package by using the control panel - didn't do anything. Still crashes immediatly. I also checked the event log. It only shows an APPCRASH-entry for excel.exe. No more details.

Excel-version: Microsoft Excel Professional Plus 16.0.9330.2124 | 64bit on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Comment: You're not going to like my suggestion, but try re-building the document (start a new workbook) with only the relevant data and see if this error reproduces. I'm pretty sure it won't *(for one reason or another...)*. If it won't, just delete the Worksheet and Copy-Replace with the one you created.

Comment: You're right - rebuilding will be hard because it is a huge file - around 100 diagramm-sheets and 100 normal worksheets. All of them linked to each other. I just tried to copy one set to a new workbook. Same crash if i try to change the sources of the diagramm with "control + left click" in the new workbook.